# How to match /debug;page=ba as a matrix variable?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, get, request-mapping

I want to match a GET request like this `/debug;page=ba`. The most intuitive way seems to use matrix variables. So following https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-matrix-variables I added

```kotlin
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun configurePathMatch(configurer: PathMatchConfigurer) {
        val urlPathHelper = UrlPathHelper()
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false)
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper)
    }
}
```

and in my controller

```
    @RequestMapping("/debug", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    @ResponseBody
    fun debug(@MatrixVariable page: String): String {
        return "page: $page"
    }
```

But this does not work. With curl, I get

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/debug;page=10
{"timestamp":"2023-05-29T10:20:55.180+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/debug"}
```

and in the browser

```txt
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon May 29 12:23:06 CEST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Why does this still not work?

Comment: This needs to be combined with URI variables.